# Buchi Automaton G(Xa->b)

Tags: automata, linear-temporal-logic, buchi-automata

I have a question regarding buchi automatons. The automata for the LTL formula, G(Xa->b) is as the attached picture. Why dosen't a have to be true in order to make the automaton correct?

[image]

My suggestion
[image]

Best regards

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The formula states that for all $n$, if $a$ holds at time $n+1$ then $b$ holds at time $n$. If $a$ never holds then the formula is trivially true.

Comment: Thank you very much, @yuval-filmus. I still not quite sure that a get the formula. The 1, does that mean "every possible value"?

Comment: Here 1 is the formula that is always true. Similarly, 0 is the formula that is always false.

Comment: Yeah, so that would be the same as the buchi, i have drawn (see newly attached picture)? Thank you for your patience :-) @yuval-filmus

Comment: I'll let you figure that out on your own.